# Passing selected value from autocomplete to another autocomplete as query string

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this autocomplete method:

```
  $("#year").autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost/ajax_autocomplete.php?type=year",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var year = ui.item.value; // need to pass year to next autocomplete
    },
  });
```

I need to use the selected year from the above code as a query string in a second autocomplete method here:

```
  $("#price").autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost/ajax_autocomplete.php?type=price&year=" + year,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // do stuff...
    },
  });
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried setting the value in `localStorage` but that will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this..

```
$(document).on('focus','.type',function(){
type = $(this).data('type');
if(type =='year' )autoTypeNo = 0; 
if(type =='price' )autoTypeNo = 1;  
$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
       $.ajax({
            url : 'autocomplete.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: type
            },
         success: function( data ) {
             response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                var code = item.split("|");
                return {
                    label: code[autoTypeNo],
                    value: code[autoTypeNo],
                    data : item
                }
            });
        }
    });
},
    autoFocus: true,           
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
        $('#year').val(names[0]);
        $('#price').val(names[1])
    }              
 });
});
```